# How to render saved data in a form so I can be edited again?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

So I have a Create Order page where you can add a part number, quantity, etc... and then you can click Save where it will then save this order to the backend. I have another page called Saved orders that renders all these saved orders in separate rows in a table with a "Edit" button next to each one. When you click "Edit" it should redirect you to the Create Order page, but instead of being empty, it should be populated with all the information for that order. So if you want you can add more items, change quantity, etc.. How would I do this? I am looking for a conceptual answer.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the idea, we don't pass lots of data via routes or even props etc. What we can do here is use the unique `id` or any other property and based on that we'll get our data and use it. There can be multiple ways to do this, I'll give you 2:

**Little setup**

Make a route for Edit which takes `id` as a param, so that for each edit we have a dynamic route, something like this:
`<Route exact path="/order/edit/:id component={CreateOrder} />`
(assuming CreateOrder is the name of the destined component).

Now your edit button should redirect to the relevant route upon click. For Class based component, you will have your button something like this:

`` <button onClick={()=>this.props.history.push(`/order/edit/${id}`)} /> ``

and on CreateOrder Component, get the value of id param in `componentDidMount` (class based) or `useEffect` hook (function based).

- for class based, you'll use `this.props.match.params.id`
- for function based, you can use `useParams()` hook, like
  `let {id} = useParams()`

As you are using same component for Creating and Editing, so apply a check on the basis of `id`, so if `id` is not null, treat your component as Edit otherwise Create.

if Edit, then either

**Make an API Call**

use your `id` to make a get request which will get all the fields for that particular order, and then set it into your `State`,

OR

**Use Browser Storage**

use browser `localStorage` or any state management tool like **Redux**, **MobX** etc and instead of calling an API get data for that particular `id` by using `Array.find()`

Based on your needs you can pick any option.