# I dont want to lose my inputing data when I pass a page in a multistep form

Tags: reactjs

so I'm making a multistep form and as you can see in the confirm page there is edit buttons that takes you back to information pages for editing data.[image]
when I click on edit for example in the personal information part and go back to that page, all fields are blank.[image]
I wanna know what should I do to inputing data not to go away when I pass that page and I can also see them when I click on edit button on the confirm page.
these are my contact and confirm components :

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm} from "react-hook-form"



import classes from '../styles.module.css'
import Input from "../UI/Input";
import Form from "../UI/Form";
import Button from "../UI/Button";


import {useAppState} from "../store/state";


const Contact = () => {

    const [state , setState] = useAppState();
   const {register, handleSubmit,watch, formState:{errors}} = useForm({
       defaultValues:{
           firstName: '',
           lastName: ''

       }})

const navigate = useNavigate()
const watchPassword = watch("Password")

   const saveData = (data) => {
     setState({...data , ...state})
       navigate("/education")}

return(

    <Form  onSubmit ={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact</legend>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="first_name"> First name</label>
                    <Input
                        type = " text"
                        {...register("firstName",
                            {required :"Firstname is required" ,
                                minLength :4  })}/>
                    <p className={classes.error}>{errors.firstName?.message}</p>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="last_name"> Last name</label>
                    <Input
                        type = " text"
                        {...register("lastName",
                            {required :'Lastname is required' ,
                                minLength :4})}/>
                    <p className={classes.error}>{errors.lastName?.message}</p>
                </div>
                <div>

                    <label htmlFor="email"> Email</label>
                    <Input type = " text"
                           {...register("email",
                               {required :"Email has to be at least four digits and include @",
                                   minLength :5, })}/>
                    <p className={classes.error}>{errors.Email?.message}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="password"> Password</label>
                    <Input
                        {...register("Password",
                            {required :'Password must be at least four digits' ,
                                minLength :4})}
                        type = "password"/>
                    <p className={classes.error}>{errors.Password?.message}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="confirm_password"> Confirm password</label>
                    <Input

                        {...register("confirmPassword", {
                            required: "Confirm the password",
                            validate: (value) =>
                                value === watchPassword || "The passwords do not match",
                        })}
                        type = "password"/>
                    <p className={classes.error}>{errors.confirmPassword?.message}</p>
                </div>

                <div className={classes.buttonRow}>
                    <Button type="submit">Next</Button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

</Form>


)

};

export default Contact;
```

and my confirm component:

```
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import {useAppState} from "../store/state";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import Form from "../UI/Form";
import EditButton from "../UI/EditButton";


const Confirm = (props) => {
    const [state] = useAppState();
    const { handleSubmit } = useForm({ defaultValues: state });

    const submitData = (data) => {
        console.info(data);
        // Submit data to the server
    };


    
return(
    <Form onSubmit = {handleSubmit(submitData)}>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Confirm</legend>
           <section>
               <div className="section mb-4">
                   <div className="title-row mb-4">
                       <h4>Personal Information</h4>
                      <EditButton/>
                   </div>
                   <div className="content">
                       <div>
                           <h5>First name</h5>
                       </div>
                       <div>{state.firstName}</div>

                        <div>
                            <h5>Last name</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>{state.lastName}</div>

                        <div>
                            <h5>Email</h5>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

            </section>

            <section>
                <div className="section mb-4">
                    <div className="title-row mb-4">
                        <h4>Education</h4>
                       <EditButton/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div>
                            <h5>University</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>{state.university}</div>

                        <div>
                            <h5>Degree</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>{state.degree}</div>


                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
            <section>
                <div className="section mb-4">
                    <div className="title-row mb-4">
                        <h4>About me</h4>
                        <EditButton/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div>
                            <h5>About me</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div>{state.about}</div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>


         <Button type = "submit">submit</Button>
            </fieldset>

    </Form>

)

};

export default Confirm
```

I saw this question that I think refers to my problem but I couldn't understand its solution.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035836/how-to-render-saved-data-in-a-form-so-i-can-be-edited-again`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035836/how-to-render-saved-data-in-a-form-so-i-can-be-edited-again%60)